# How to find Entity ManyToMany

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entity Post and Tags this entity have relationship ManyToMany, many post have many tags and many tags have many posts and have Entity Category I Many post for one category and I need create action for find post for category and find post for tag

```
class Tag
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $hashTag;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"hashTag"})
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=12)
 */
protected $hashSlug;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="tag")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $post;
```

category:

```
class Category
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=64)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $posts;
```

post

```
class Post
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $title;
    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="post")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="posts_tag")
 */
protected $tag;
```

and my template I post in my action field hashTag:

```
    <p class="lead">
    Category:<a href="{{ path('get_posts_for_category', {'category': post.category.title}) }}">{{ post.category }}</a>
    </p>
 {% for tags in post.tag %}
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ path('get_posts_for_tags', {'tags': tags }) }}">{{ tags }} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    {% endfor %}


public function indexAction(Request $request, $tag)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $posts = $em->getRepository('PillsBundle:Post')
        ->getPostByTag($tags);
```

end this is function:

```
    public function getPostByTag($tag)
{
    $date = new \DateTime;

    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('p');

    $qb
        ->select('p')
        ->from('PillsBundle:Post', 'p')
        ->getQuery();

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();
    //        dump($results);exit; => I have all posts
    // And I dont know what to do next, help
}
```

and for category:

```
    public function indexAction(Request $request, $category)
    {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $posts = $em->getRepository('PillsBundle:Post')
        ->getPostByCategory($category);
    public function getPostByCategory($category)
{
    $date = new \DateTime;

    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('p');

    $qb ->select('p')
        ->from('PillsBundle:Post', 'p')
        ->join('p.category', 'c')
        ->where('c = :category')
        ->setParameter('category', $category)
        ->getQuery();

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();

    return $results;
}
```

If I use this QueryBuilder what I post (now I post categoty.slug) for this function needed? 
Help please

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the tag into the query so...

```
public function getPostByTag($tag)
{
    $date = new \DateTime;

    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('p');

    $qb
        ->select('p')
        ->from('PillsBundle:Post', 'p')
        ->join('p.tag', 't')
        ->where('t = :tag')
        ->setParameter('tag', $tag)
        ->getQuery();

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();

    return $results;
}
```

Should be working like this, but you should change your names, is quite confusing, if you send just one tag, you have to call it tag, not tags. And always when you have many tags which belongs to an entity you have to call it tags, plural

Comment: I update my question. $tag its not entity clas Tag, this is field hashTag, and in template I forin Posts and in this foring tag and post in action hasTag `{% for tags in post.tag %}
        <a href="{{ path('get_posts_for_tags', {'tags': tags }) }}">{{ tags }} </a>
        {% endfor %}`

Comment: I have relationship ManyToMany, single table, tag_id post_id

Comment: If I use this QueryBuilder what I post (now I post tags.hashSlug) for this function needed?

Comment: This should be `{% for tags in post.tags %} <a href="{{ path('get_posts_for_tags', {'tags': tags }) }}">{{ tags }} </a> {% endfor %}`

Comment: I understand that but I need find post for tag with createQueryBuilder

Comment: Is not working the solution that I gave you? What error is throwing?